# color_continuous_scale doesn't apply to the plotly graph

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-dash

I have the same jupyter notebook running on google collaboratory and on my local machine (macos on Vscode)

When I print the plotly chart with color_continuous_scale='bluyl' scheme it prints correctly with that scheme in collaboratory but not on my local machine. I can't figure out what the issue is. The legend on the side of the chart is also displayed differently in Collaboratory and local machine.

Following is the code I am using to generate the graph:

```
data_2023=data[data['2023_participation'] > 0].copy()

fig_participation_2023 = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    data_2023,
    geojson=geo_json,
    locations='Country',
    color='2023_participation',
    color_continuous_scale='bluyl',
    range_color=(0, data_2023['2023_participation'].max()),
    hover_name=data_2023['Name of Institution'],
    mapbox_style='carto-positron',
    zoom=1,
    center={'lat': 19, 'lon': 11},
    opacity=0.6
)

fig_participation_2023.update_layout(
    title='2023 Participation',
    height=1000
)

# Display figure
fig_participation_2023.show()
```

Following is the output on google collaboratory and on local machine.

**How can I get the local machine output to look the same as google collaboratory?**

Google collab:

[image]

Local machine:

[image]

Comment: Can you give us the package version you're using on both sides please?

Comment: For the google collaboratory, the plotly version is: 5.13.1
for local macbook: '5.15.0'

Comment: The problem may be before the plotly code. Please look at the data import, content and types of data['2023_participation']. Are they both float, or is one int or even string?

Comment: '2023_participation' column only contains ints. Also The data displayed in both charts is the same, issue lies in thecolor scheme not being applied